# Async method .Result vs Sync method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Do these two methods work the same way? Both of these block the main thread, don't they?

```
// 1. Use async method
public IEnumerable<Entity> AsyncMethod()
{
    return Context.Entities.ToListAsync().Result;
}

// 2. Use sync method
public IEnumerable<Entity> SyncMethod()
{
    return Context.Entities.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading [this article by Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: The question is unclear; what *precisely* do you mean by "block"?  Blocking a thread has a specific technical meaning; calling a synchronous API does not *block* a thread; it executes code on the thread! That's the opposite of blocking a thread. Executing code on a thread prevents that thread from servicing any other requests; is that what you mean by "blocking"?

Comment: Thanks, yes, you right, it's that I mean.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the *specific* APIs you mention, I do not know whether they are the same or not; an expert on those APIs should answer.

In *general*, if there is a synchronous API and an asynchronous API, is taking the result of the asynchronous API guaranteed to be the same as the synchronous API?

**No**. A synchronous API should, as part of its contract, guarantee that it produces either a result or an exception in a reasonable amount of time.  *Taking the `Result` of an asynchronous API is permitted to "deadlock"*.

That's because an asynchronous API is permitted to work by *scheduling work to be done on the current thread in the future*, and then *running the continuation of the associated task after it is complete*.  By requiring the `Result` synchronously, you can get into a situation where work is scheduled to be run *in the future* on this thread, but this thread is now blocking until the work is done, and we have a single-threaded deadlock situation.

For more details about why this causes deadlock and how to prevent it, please refer to [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

It is almost *never* the right thing to do to get the `Result` of a task. If you need the result of a task, `await` it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this two methods works the same way? Both of this block main thread, isn't?

Both blocks the main thread. So effectively it behaves in the same way.

First approach `ToList` is `async` and `Result` would block until the `ToList` task complete. Second approach is not `async`.

When it come to just `ToList`, using of `Result` may not make much sense.

Comment: Thanks, I know, that using `Result` doesn't make sense. It's just for understanding. [This article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) says that `Result` are blocks context and it's bad, but I want to understand is it the same behavioud if I use not-async equivalent of the method.

Comment: Yes, pretty much the same behavior. ToListAsync uses a separate thread, but Result is blocking the main thread until the ToList completes. So the behavior is the same or the second approach is better for simple toList.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this two methods works the same way?

Yes, essentially the two methods work the same way.

> Both of this block main thread, isn't?

With the `ToList` being an `async`, the `Results` would stop until the `ToList` task is fully complete.